# I want to upload photos from android to server using php but my php script generates error

Tags: php, android, mysql

The error generated is: -:500:there is a problem with the resource you are looking for
however when i upload it locally it is successfully uploaded

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $profile_id = $_POST['profile_id'];
    require_once('Constants.php');

    $path = "imageUploads/eimg1/$profile_id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://raj.familybook.co.in/$path";

    $sql = "update info set extra_image_1 ='$actualpath' where
    profile_id='$profile_id'";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

please help me ,any help from your side will be appreciated

Comment: the error just 500 no any details

Comment: Check the return of `file_put_contents()`, it's probably permissions. Also, "Error" is not useful information, but [`mysqli_error()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) is.

Comment: yes :the error msg i m getting is " 500 :internal server error there is a problemwith the resource you are looking for and it cannot be displayed"

Comment: i have added mysqli_error() still it is not generating any error